# how to fix isAuthorized issue in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Hi I just observe a very strange behaviour with my isAuthorized(). I have my parent function returning true but still access is denied to my action. what could I be missing... Thanks
PARENT FUNCTION

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
        $granted = $this->getGrant($user);
        return ($granted === '1') ? true : false;
    }
```

CHILD FUNCTION

```
public function isAuthorized($user){
        return parent::isAuthorized($user);
    }
```

I debugged $granted and it returns '1' but still I'm denied access to my (priviledge)action. NOTE: This does not occur in all cases though... I have a /groups controller and /groups/priviledge controller and action. isAuthorized() works well with the former but not with the later. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: ($granted === '1') evaluates to boolean, no need to have "?true:false" appended. Also why are you overriding the function in the child when it would be inherited (and callable) anyways?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
return ($granted === 1) ? true : false;
```

Comment: Possibly use `return (intval($granted)===1);` instead, to ensure type matching.

Comment: To no avail guys... Tried both. This is quite strange and frustrating to me. What possibly could be wrong???

Comment: @Luvy_soLs Try a hardcoded `return true;` to test whether there is a type mismatch problem at all.

Comment: Exactly man I tried a hard coded return true; It works. But when I try to return true with the above condition it won't just work!!!. Strange really because on debug() it returns true but it won't just work!!!. I am confused!!!